# IMAP to disk mail archiver

Tags: windows, gratis, email, archiving, imap

I need a **mail archiving tool** that

- can connect to an **IMAP** server (port 25 / TLS)
- can fetch incoming and outgoing emails (certain folders)
- batch save them to disk as HTML
- with a configurable filename pattern, which can include

  - sender
  - receiver
  - subject
  - date / time
- also **saves attachments**.

A GUI is not mandatory.

Answer (score 3):

Judging from the title (i.e. ignoring the "windows" tag and the "port 25" you want to connect to), I'd recommend either [Archivemail](http://archivemail.sourceforge.net/) or [offlineimap](http://offlineimap.org/).

You can read about **Archivemail** in it's [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/archivemail). From the synopsis:

> archivemail is a tool for archiving and compressing old email in
>   mailboxes. By default it will read the mailbox MAILBOX, moving
>   messages that are older that the specified number of days (180 by
>   default) to a mbox(5)-format mailbox in the same directory that is
>   compressed with gzip(1). It can also just delete old email rather than
>   archive it.
>
> archivemail supports reading IMAP, Maildir, MH and mbox-format
>   mailboxes, but always writes mbox-format archives.

I am tempted to say that **offlineimap** ([man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/offlineimap)) is a bit more powerful, but that depends on your needs.

> OfflineImap operates on a REMOTE and a LOCAL repository and
>   synchronizes emails between them, so that you can read the same
>   mailbox from multiple computers. The REMOTE repository is some IMAP
>   server, while LOCAL can be either a local Maildir or another IMAP
>   server.

I don't think any of those can save every mail with a filename pattern you desire, but with maildir every email is a file and you could open every file, extract the desired information and rename the file. That sounds like a hundred lines of Python.